# Flutter app works differently on release build

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, build

Lately, I've added new screen to an app, which I've been working on, and it seems like app renders it differently on Release build. I've tried flutter clean, and deleting build directory on my own. Here's how it looks like

[Screen on release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgHnf.png)

[Screen on debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0XvS.png)

What's interesting, on different set of data it seems like it works just fine on release

[Same screen on release, different data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyBVu.png)

[Same screen on debug, different data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aYiO.png)

Comment: post code sample for people to be able to help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is no weird thing. in debug mode whenever there is an error or warning app jump from that and continue rendering but in release mode, it just stops rendering and show a blank gray page... for release you should make sure there is absolutely no warning and errors in your code

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It turned out, that there's some kind of error, which was ignored in debug, so it went unnoticed. I'm going to fix it, and let's hope that it will solve my problem :D

Comment: if it helps please mark it as an answer thank you